# $f(x)=1$; $x$ is in cantors set and $0$ when $x$ is not in cantors set...check continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, cantor-set

$f$ is a function defined from $[0,1]$ to $\{0,1\}$ as $f(x)=1$ when $x$ belongs to $C$ and $f(x)=0$ when $x$ does not belong to $C$,where $C$ is cantor's set.

> Show that $f$ is not continuous on any point of its domain.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: You mean $f(x)=0$ when $x$ does not belong to $C$.

Comment: @Arthur I know M is disconnected when there is an contionous surjection from M to {0,1}, If there is a such fn in my case that would imply [0,1] is diconnected....so there will be no such fn...but i need to show that this fn is nowhere cts..

Comment: @freakish ..yes sorry for the mistake....there f(x)=0

Comment: Perhaps there is some mistake. The function (as defined) *is* continuous on many points of its domain--in fact, it only fails to be continuous on a (very particular) set of measure $0$. For example, $f$ is the constant  $0$ function on the interval $(1/3,2/3),$ so is continuous there.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I don't think this is right. For example $f$ is continuous on $\frac{1}{2}$. Indeed, for $\varepsilon:=\frac{1}{12}$ (for simplicity), $f([\frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon,\frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon])=\{0\}$, as $[\frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon,\frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon]$ do not contains any Cantor's Set's points